# Form submit with 2 buttons + sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a form in which 2 submit button.

1. For- Publish story
2. For- Draft story

If an user click on Publish story, story will be publish, simply.
But if an user click on Draft story, an alert (which is [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)) will be appear for confirmation that this user actually want to save this story in Draft.
**PS**: I am also using [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) in my form.
**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" name="storyForm" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="storyTitle" required>
  <input name="storyDetail" required>
  <input name="storyCategory" required>

  <button type="submit" onclick="storyPublish()">Publish</button>
  <button type="submit" onclick="storyDraft()">Draft</button>
</form>
```

Previously I was using this javascript for submitting form but now I want sweetalert before sending it to **Draft**:

```
function storyPublish()
{
    document.storyForm.action = "ePHP/storyPublish.php"
    document.storyForm["storyForm"].submit();

}
function storyDraft()
{
    document.storyForm.action = "ePHP/storyDraft.php"
    document.storyForm["storyForm"].submit();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried something for you, is this the same thing what you want?

```js
function storyPublish(e)
{
    $(".validated").jqBootstrapValidation(
    {
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // Here I do nothing, but you could do something like display 
            // the error messages to the user, log, etc.
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            document.storyForm.action = "ePHP/storyPublish.php"
            document.storyForm.submit();    
    
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        }
    }
  );
}
function storyDraft(event)
{
    $(".validated").jqBootstrapValidation(
    {
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // Here I do nothing, but you could do something like display 
            // the error messages to the user, log, etc.
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
                swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You want to save as draft?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, Draft it!",
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!"
        }).then((result) => {
            if(result.value){
                document.storyForm.action = "ePHP/storyDraft.php";
                document.storyForm.submit();
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
            }
        });   
    
        event.preventDefault();
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.1.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form method="POST" name="storyForm" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class='control-group'>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="storyTitle" class='validated' id='storyTitle' required data-validation-required-message='test'>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='control-group'>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="storyDetail" class='validated' required>
            <p class="help-block"></p> 
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class='control-group'>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="storyCategory" class='validated' required>
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-action'>
        <button type="submit" onclick="storyPublish(event)">Publish</button>
        <button type="submit" onclick="storyDraft(event)">Draft</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Actually in your means you are right. But the thing is I already tried that. It is not validating form. That the respected fields are empty or not!

Comment: I have updated my answer please check now, I have added jquery validation @GermanCoder

Comment: @GermanCoder again I have updated to sweetalert original before I have used bootstrap-sweetalert, please check that

Comment: I have checked your updated script and I have no idea why it is not working on my script. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: I was a lil bit wrong above, I am using [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) could you please check with it.

Comment: can u please check in console if you found any error in developer console tab, and again I have updated the code with sweetalert main script instead of bootstrap please copy that

Comment: let me check with that i have implemented with jqueryValidation plugin

Comment: In console it says `.valid is not a function` and also `.validate is not a function`

Comment: its due to jquery validation plugin let me check with jqBootstrapValidation for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162012/discussion-between-germancoder-and-prateik-darji).

Comment: @GermanCoder please check I have updated the code and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Exactly that is what I want. Thank you so much for help. My brain is totally ended up!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this.

```js
$('#draft').on('click', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault()
  swal({
    title: 'You want to save?',
    text: "You can come back to this later!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, save it!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
   let data = $('form').serialize();
      let urlToPostTo = 'https://posttestserver.com/post.php';
    $.post(urlToPostTo, data, function(){
          swal(
            'Saved!',
            'Your file has been saved.',
            'success'
          )
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="ePHP/storyPublish.php" method="post">
  <input name="storyTitle">
  <input name="storyDetail">
  <input name="storyCategory">
  <button type="submit">Publish</button>
  <button id="draft" type="submit">Draft</button>
</form>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.1.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: ^I didn't do that I am sorry. You're also right in your means but It your script in also not validating form.